# Why am I having problems passing argument to or from a FORTRAN DLL from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6, fortran, vb6-migration

I have a DLL written in fortran that I know works because I am getting it from a working software package that we use daily.  I am trying to call it from anything but am having problems i believe with passing the correctly formatted arguments in and out of it, so i decided to try and access it from a VB program.  I chose VB because I have contacted the developer of the software package we are using and he gave me his DLL function call in VB6, even though he is not allowed to show me the FORTRAN source.

Problem is (perhaps, i think) that I am writing in VB.NET, which has different data types than VB6.  Can anyone see why i am am having problems.

The error i get upon running is: "AccessViolationException was unhandled: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Here is the function call i was supplied with:

```
Declare Sub FCC_Curves Lib "FCC_Curves.dll" (Read_Flag As Boolean, First_Flag As Boolean, Frequency_MHz As Single, IQT As Integer,  ByVal Radiation_Opt As String, ByVal L1 As Long,  ERP_Watts As Single, T_PowerWatts As Single, Tx_GaindBi As Single, T_Loss As Single, ByVal Service As String, ByVal L2 As Long, Reliability As Integer, ByVal FCC_CurvesDataPath As String, ByVal L3 As Long,  ByVal TerrainRoughness As String, ByVal L4 As Long, Haatm As Single, NPRfl As Integer, NFCCCurve As Integer, HPRfl As Single,  Crve As Single, FCC_Loss As Single, Code As Integer, FS As Single)
```

and here is my code:

```
Module Module1

    Declare Sub FCC_Curves Lib "FCC_Curves.dll" (ByVal Read_Flag As Boolean, ByVal First_Flag As Boolean, ByVal Frequency_MHz As Single, ByVal IQT As Int16, ByVal Radiation_Opt As String, ByVal L1 As Int32, ByVal ERP_Watts As Single, ByVal T_PowerWatts As Single, ByVal Tx_GaindBi As Single, ByVal T_Loss As Single, ByVal Service As String, ByVal L2 As Int32, ByVal Reliability As Int16, ByVal FCC_CurvesDataPath As String, ByVal L3 As Int32, ByVal TerrainRoughness As String, ByVal L4 As Int32, ByVal Haatm As Single, ByVal NPRfl As Int16, ByVal NFCCCurve As Int16, ByVal HPRfl() As Single, ByVal Crve() As Single, ByRef FCC_Loss As Single, ByRef Code As Int16, ByRef FS() As Single)


    Sub Main()

        Dim Read_Flag As Boolean
        Dim First_Flag As Boolean
        Dim Frequency_MHz As Single
        Dim IQT As Int16
        Dim Radiation_Opt As String
        Dim L1 As Int32
        Dim ERP_Watts As Single
        Dim T_PowerWatts As Single
        Dim Tx_GaindBi As Single
        Dim T_Loss As Single
        Dim Service As String
        Dim L2 As Int32
        Dim Reliability As Int16
        Dim FCC_CurvesDataPath As String
        Dim L3 As Int32
        Dim TerrainRoughness As String
        Dim L4 As Int32
        Dim Haatm As Single
        Dim NPRfl As Int16
        Dim NFCCCurve As Int16
        Dim HPRfl(12) As Single
        Dim Crve(5) As Single
        Dim FCC_Loss As Single
        Dim Code As Int16
        Dim FS(15) As Single
        'Dim HPRfl As Single
        'Dim Crve As Single
        'Dim FCC_Loss As Single
        'Dim Code As Int16
        'Dim FS As Single

        Read_Flag = True
        First_Flag = True
        Frequency_MHz = 98.1
        IQT = 0
        Radiation_Opt = "ERP"
        L1 = 3
        ERP_Watts = 1000
        T_PowerWatts = 1000
        Tx_GaindBi = 2.15
        T_Loss = 0
        Service = "Broadcast"
        L2 = 9
        Reliability = 50
        FCC_CurvesDataPath = "C:\Program Files\CSPT_Extension\data\"
        L3 = 37
        TerrainRoughness = "Off"
        L4 = 3
        Haatm = 1500
        NPRfl = 13
        NFCCCurve = 6
        Dim i As Int16
        HPRfl(0) = 11
        HPRfl(1) = 128
        For i = 2 To 12
            HPRfl(i) = 1500
        Next
        For i = 0 To 5
            Crve(i) = i * 15
        Next



        FCC_Curves(Read_Flag, First_Flag, Frequency_MHz, IQT, Radiation_Opt, L1, ERP_Watts, T_PowerWatts, Tx_GaindBi, T_Loss, Service, L2, Reliability, FCC_CurvesDataPath, L3, TerrainRoughness, L4, Haatm, NPRfl, NFCCCurve, HPRfl, Crve, FCC_Loss, Code, FS)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.  In VB6 the argument that do not otherwise specify are by default passed to functions as ByRef.  In VB.NET if you leave an argument blank in the function declaration, it automatically inserts ByVal, which seems to therefore be the defacto default.  VB.NET forces you to specify in other words, so if you are taking a function declaration from VB6 to VB.NET, know that the unmarked default in VB6 is ByRef.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the VB.NET data types are not compatible with the VB6 ones.  A VB6 Integer is now a Short (aka Int16).  A VB6 Long is now an Integer (aka Int32).  A VB6 Boolean was an odd duck, now equivalent to Short where the value True is -1 and False is 0.

Start by changing Long in the function declaration to Integer, that's the Big One.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's necessary to use the Auto keyword in an external function with string parameters.

```
Declare Auto Sub FCC_Curves Lib...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post my experience passing arguments from VB.net (.net v5, VS 64bit v17.0.5) to dll created with gfortran 7.3.0(in code::blocks).  The example shows  passing integers, a byte array, and a way to handle a character string passing via the byte array.  I'm not a pro-programmer, programming is just a tool for me, so my "programming vernacular" may not be correct.  Note I'm running these codes on a 64bit machine using Windows 10 (64bit).
First, the fortran code for the dll:

```
  subroutine intmul(i,j,k,n)
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL, DLLEXPORT :: intmul
      integer, intent(inout) :: i,j,n
      integer*1, intent(inout) :: k(j)
      character test*100
      test=''
      do 1 m=1,j
      test(m:m)=char(k(m))
    1 continue
      n=22
      i=16
      open (unit=10,file='testchr.txt',status='unknown',
     cform='formatted')
      write (10,2) trim(test)
    2 format (a)
      close (unit=10)

      end subroutine
```

The arguments n and j are just for demonstration purposes.  Argument j is input and represents the length of the string (i.e. the number of elements in the Integer*1 (byte) array k.  The byte array is reconstructed as a text string and written to a file.

The calling VB code is:

```
    Module Module0
        '
        ' test passing integers and character string via byte array
        'j=length of character string (i.e. n will have j elements 0 to j-1)
        'i and kk are just some dummy test arguments
        Declare Auto Sub intmul Lib "D:\test\vb-fortan\dlls\intandarraychr\bin\Debug\fd1.dll" Alias _
          "intmul_" (ByRef i As Int32, ByRef j As Int32, ByVal n() As Byte, ByRef kk As Int32)
    End Module

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        End
    End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            Dim i, j, k As Int32
            Dim m(100) As Byte
            Dim testtext As String
            testtext = TextBox4.Text
            i = TextBox3.Text
            j = testtext.Length   'length of string ==> number of elements in byte array to pass
            k = TextBox5.Text
            '  Convert unicode text (2 bytes/character) to byte array with each element
            'of the array containing the code for each character
            m = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testtext)
    
            MsgBox("proceed")
            Call intmul(i, j, m, k)
            TextBox3.Text = i
            TextBox5.Text = k
        End Sub
   
    End Class
```

Note: VB code was compiled using the "Any CPU" platform setting.
Note the array is passed "byval" --- I noticed even though I specified STDCALL when I tried to pass an array byref the address of the address of the array was pushed to the stack rather than the address of the array.  If I pass byval the address of the array is pushed to the stack which is what I thought was proper STDCALL..???  Anyway passing an array byval has the same effect as passing byref.

As to determining the dependencies in the fortran dll -- my solution, albeit brute force, is to copy ALL the dlls within the gfortran folders to a folder on another machine without any of the development tools and which contains the necessary files for the VB code itself.  Run the code that calls the fortran dll of interest.   Then examine the last access date/time of the all the dll's to see which have been accessed.  If it wasn't accessed then you don't need it...this is an alternative to wading through the output of Dependency Walker.
Hope this helps save someone the amount of time I spent running this to ground.